# Provider hosted app: TokenHelper not authorized to get context

Tags: client-object-model, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, provider-hosted-app

I followed [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/package-and-publish-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins#configure-the-remote-web-server-with-the-certificate) tutorial to deploy Provider Hosted App to production environment. It has a proper SSL certificate installed, it's registered within SharePoint and TokenHelper class is modified. App permissions are set to Full Control for web and site collection.

When I use `TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false)` or `TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties)` methods to get **ClientContext**, it's returned null and the code throws 401 Unauthorized exception.

I get a proper ClientContext when I create it manually and provide the credentials of farm admin account, but it's not an acceptable solution for production. Also, from the two methods, what is the correct way to get ClientContext in this case?

Comment: Refer this link - https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/07/remote-event-receivers-on-host-web-ClientContext.html

Comment: @RohitWaghela from this article, I'm using `TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken()` method and I'm getting a Web Exception that tenant with given ID has not been found, even though ID is correct.